# Troubles interacting with Chainlink node on Kovan

Tags: oracles, chainlink, kovan

I've been following instructions on [running a local Chainlink node](https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink) on Kovan. My environment is configured to Kovan through websockets via Infura and the node is both running and successfully accepts ETH and LINK transfers over Kovan:
[image: Chainlink node with ETH and LINK transfers over Kovan]

The sample Oracle.sol contract was deployed on Kovan `0xa36085F69e2889c224210F603D836748e7dC0088` and the address of the node set with `true` value under `setFulfillmentPermission`:
[image: Oracle.sol deployment on Kovan]

I created a sample job with toml that creates successfully and generates a public job id:
[image: job with public id]

The job id above is `"5bdce20f-e3ef-4aa9-b5e2-89e1b523ca7d"` and I set this in my contract as `"5bdce20fe3ef4aa9b5e289e1b523ca7d"`. No matter the implementation, I have not been able to identify any runs on my console and they fail each time. This includes two variations of sample contracts I have been unsuccessful to transmit the run:
[image: sample contract fail]

Besides reverting to an earlier version to deploy a node that transacts jobs under v1, I don't know how to go about debugging and getting the local node to acknowledge a run. Looking for help. Please let me know if there's any specific info I can provide to help.

---

1. Oracle.sol smart contract deployed at address 0x2559c36Aee1dC9231d679D9b456265a46049dBfD
2. node wallet at address 0x58320a1e8377b6143614944b5418E71FEE35D7a8
3. job id 5bdce20f-e3ef-4aa9-b5e2-89e1b523ca7d

##### sample contracts:

[`ATestnetConsumer`](http://remix.ethereum.org/#url=https://docs.chain.link/samples/APIRequests/ATestnetConsumer.sol&optimize=false&runs=200&evmVersion=null&version=soljson-v0.8.7+commit.e28d00a7.js) method `RequestEthereumChange` called with `"0x2559c36Aee1dC9231d679D9b456265a46049dBfD", "5bdce20fe3ef4aa9b5e289e1b523ca7d"` results in error:

```
status  false Transaction mined but execution failed
transaction hash    0xa5df1f36059f45b7b8f400166d0a2cd12654a4987e7129a0551e9fcb64b5fb9e
from    0x4de15D18F9dF69B52E249D5033458ecf4acc547d
to  ATestnetConsumer.requestEthereumChange(address,string) 0xE4492b62b2a1D27Fb694eD6AcAC05C4e5ee6E63A
gas 3000000 gas
transaction cost    2954345 gas 
hash    0xa5df1f36059f45b7b8f400166d0a2cd12654a4987e7129a0551e9fcb64b5fb9e
input   0x619...13764
decoded input   {
    "address _oracle": "0x2559c36Aee1dC9231d679D9b456265a46049dBfD",
    "string _jobId": "5bdce20fe3ef4aa9b5e289e1b523ca7d"
}
decoded output   - 
logs    []
val 0 wei
```

---

[`APIConsumer`](https://remix.ethereum.org/#url=https://docs.chain.link/samples/APIRequests/APIConsumer.sol&optimize=false&runs=200&evmVersion=null&version=soljson-v0.8.7+commit.e28d00a7.js) method `requestVolumeData` results in error with following implementation:

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/ChainlinkClient.sol";

/**
 * THIS IS AN EXAMPLE CONTRACT WHICH USES HARDCODED VALUES FOR CLARITY.
 * PLEASE DO NOT USE THIS CODE IN PRODUCTION.
 */
contract APIConsumer is ChainlinkClient {
    using Chainlink for Chainlink.Request;
  
    uint256 public volume;
    
    address private oracle;
    bytes32 private jobId;
    uint256 private fee;
    
    /**
     * Network: Kovan
     * Oracle: 0xc57B33452b4F7BB189bB5AfaE9cc4aBa1f7a4FD8 (Chainlink Devrel   
     * Node)
     * Job ID: d5270d1c311941d0b08bead21fea7747
     * Fee: 0.1 LINK
     */
    constructor() {
        setPublicChainlinkToken();
        oracle = 0x2559c36Aee1dC9231d679D9b456265a46049dBfD;
        jobId = "5bdce20fe3ef4aa9b5e289e1b523ca7d";
        fee = 0.1 * 10 ** 18; // (Varies by network and job)
    }
    
    /**
     * Create a Chainlink request to retrieve API response, find the target
     * data, then multiply by 1000000000000000000 (to remove decimal places from data).
     */
    function requestVolumeData() public returns (bytes32 requestId) 
    {
        Chainlink.Request memory request = buildChainlinkRequest(jobId, address(this), this.fulfill.selector);
        
        // Set the URL to perform the GET request on
        request.add("get", "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemultifull?fsyms=ETH&tsyms=USD");
        
        // Set the path to find the desired data in the API response, where the response format is:
        // {"RAW":
        //   {"ETH":
        //    {"USD":
        //     {
        //      "VOLUME24HOUR": xxx.xxx,
        //     }
        //    }
        //   }
        //  }
        request.add("path", "RAW.ETH.USD.VOLUME24HOUR");
        
        // Multiply the result by 1000000000000000000 to remove decimals
        int timesAmount = 10**18;
        request.addInt("times", timesAmount);
        
        // Sends the request
        return sendChainlinkRequestTo(oracle, request, fee);
    }
    
    /**
     * Receive the response in the form of uint256
     */ 
    function fulfill(bytes32 _requestId, uint256 _volume) public recordChainlinkFulfillment(_requestId)
    {
        volume = _volume;
    }

    // function withdrawLink() external {} - Implement a withdraw function to avoid locking your LINK in the contract
}
```

Comment: hi @aug2uag, at what point does it fail. Does the job request not even reach the node and it fails in your function call on-chain? If so, can you please update your post with the function code that you are calling, and specify the passed in parameters? If it's reaching the node but failing at the node, please post the full json output of the job that fails

Comment: @HarryPapacharissiou thanks for your response. That's correct, the job does not reach the node and fails on-chain. The list of runs is empty and says `No jobs have been run yet`. Included implementation details as edit above.

Comment: what's the error that's given? your consumer contract above is different from the remix screenshot further up that shows an error (requestEthereumChange function). I threw the APIConsumer above into remix and it worked ok.

If you're using the contract further up (the requestEthereumChange function), then suggest try changing the jobId param input to a string, and then converting it to bytes32 with a function like this example here, remix can be a bit funny with passing in byte32 as params.  https://github.com/smartcontractkit/hardhat-starter-kit/blob/main/contracts/APIConsumer.sol

Comment: @HarryPapacharissiou "I threw the APIConsumer above into remix and it worked ok", I'm certain the APIConsumer would work, yet with a local jobs v2 node deployment on Kovan is not working for me. The node is functional and job is created, however a run is never created. Have you tried deploying to Kovan from the latest codebase and deploying v2 job as above? I pasted the error for requestEthereumChange, it is the same result for requestVolumeData. I can't keep dashes in the jobId, it doesn't fit to bytes32 constraint.

Comment: @HarryPapacharissiou the .env file for my node [was configured from online resource](https://docs.chain.link/docs/running-a-chainlink-node/#create-an-environment-file) and includes `LINK_CONTRACT_ADDRESS=0xa36085F69e2889c224210F603D836748e7dC0088`, it's not clear what this contract should be pointing to, the deployed Oracle.sol or leave the default val?

Comment: it's LINK on Kovan, seems to be alright-- I'm reconfiguring a node with Docker on VPS to see if it makes a difference

Comment: in VPS I'm getting the same results, I can't tell what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 1):

what I did wrong, in case it helps others:

1. jobs are highly specific pipelines, in tutorials make sure your job correlates to the smart contract
2. the contract may require to be funded with LINK, make sure the contract is funded if it's required